# Why does npm-remote-ls miss a dependency listed in a module's package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Say I have the following nodejs script:

```
let ls = require('npm-remote-ls').ls
let config = require('npm-remote-ls').config
config({development:false,optional:true})
ls('node-gyp','9.3.1',console.log)
```

It logs:

```
{
  'node-gyp@9.3.1': {
    'env-paths@2.2.1': {},
    'graceful-fs@4.2.11': {},
    'npmlog@6.0.2': {
      'are-we-there-yet@3.0.1': [Object],
      'set-blocking@2.0.0': {},
      'console-control-strings@1.1.0': {},
      'gauge@4.0.4': [Object]
    },
    'rimraf@3.0.2': { 'glob@7.2.3': {} },
    'glob@7.2.3': {
      'fs.realpath@1.0.0': {},
      'inflight@1.0.6': [Object],
      'inherits@2.0.4': {},
      'path-is-absolute@1.0.1': {},
      'minimatch@3.1.2': [Object],
      'once@1.4.0': [Object]
    },
    'semver@7.5.1': { 'lru-cache@6.0.0': [Object] },
    'make-fetch-happen@10.2.1': {
      'agentkeepalive@4.3.0': [Object],
      'http-cache-semantics@4.1.1': {},
      'cacache@16.1.3': [Object],
      'http-proxy-agent@5.0.0': [Object],
      'https-proxy-agent@5.0.1': [Object],
      'is-lambda@1.0.1': {},
      'minipass-collect@1.0.2': [Object],
      'lru-cache@7.18.3': {},
      'minipass@3.3.6': [Object],
      'minipass-flush@1.0.5': [Object],
      'minipass-pipeline@1.2.4': [Object],
      'promise-retry@2.0.1': [Object],
      'socks-proxy-agent@7.0.0': [Object],
      'ssri@9.0.1': [Object],
      'minipass-fetch@2.1.2': [Object],
      'negotiator@0.6.3': {}
    },
    'which@2.0.2': { 'isexe@2.0.0': {} },
    'tar@6.1.15': {
      'fs-minipass@2.1.0': [Object],
      'minipass@5.0.0': {},
      'minizlib@2.1.2': [Object],
      'mkdirp@1.0.4': {},
      'yallist@4.0.0': {},
      'chownr@2.0.0': {}
    },
    'nopt@6.0.0': { 'abbrev@1.1.1': {} }
  }
}
```

The [package.json for node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/aaa117c514430aa2c1e568b95df1b6ed1c1fd3b6/package.json#LL26C5-L26C37) includes `"exponential-backoff": "^3.1.1",` in the `dependencies` field, so I'd expect to see it in the above output; but I'm not.

Why am I not getting `exponential-backoff` listed in npm-remote-ls's output? How could I adjust the script to get a full list of dependencies? Or is there another, easier, way to get a full list of dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version `9.3.1` does not have `exponential-backoff` as a dependency, that's why it is not showing. See the `package.json`for [version 9.3.1 here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/9.3.1?activeTab=code).

If you change to the `latest` version which is `10.0.1` it **is** a dependency.

```js
ls('node-gyp','latest',console.log)
```

Then `"exponential-backoff": "^3.1.1"` is there:

```js
{
  'node-gyp@10.0.1': {
    'semver@7.5.4': { 'lru-cache@6.0.0': [Object] },
    'nopt@7.2.0': { 'abbrev@2.0.0': {} },
    'which@4.0.0': { 'isexe@3.1.1': {} },
    'proc-log@3.0.0': {},
    'tar@6.2.0': {
      'fs-minipass@2.1.0': [Object],
      'minipass@5.0.0': {},
      'mkdirp@1.0.4': {},
      'minizlib@2.1.2': [Object],
      'chownr@2.0.0': {},
      'yallist@4.0.0': {}
    },
    'graceful-fs@4.2.11': {},
    'make-fetch-happen@13.0.0': {
      'cacache@18.0.0': [Object],
      'minipass-fetch@3.0.4': [Object],
      'minipass@7.0.4': {},
      'minipass-flush@1.0.5': [Object],
      'minipass-pipeline@1.2.4': [Object],
      'negotiator@0.6.3': {},
      'promise-retry@2.0.1': [Object],
      'ssri@10.0.5': [Object],
      'http-cache-semantics@4.1.1': {},
      'is-lambda@1.0.1': {},
      '@npmcli/agent@2.2.0': [Object]
    },
    'glob@10.3.10': {
      'foreground-child@3.1.1': [Object],
      'minimatch@9.0.3': [Object],
      'minipass@7.0.4': {},
      'jackspeak@2.3.6': [Object],
      'path-scurry@1.10.1': [Object]
    },
    'env-paths@2.2.1': {},
    'exponential-backoff@3.1.1': {}
  }
}
```

It looks like it was brought in for version [9.4.0 here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/9.4.0?activeTab=code) so you are probably looking at a git commit between versions.

Comment: Thanks, my main lesson is that npmjs.com is the authoritative source and that it may not match the code repository.

Comment: @Lee you're welcome. Yes NPM is the correct source. To be honest I was stumped for 10 minutes trying to figure out why GutHub had it as a dependency but then the penny dropped. Good luck with your project.